# No funciona redirect yii2

Tags: yii2

Buenas tardes
Espero puedan ayudarme, tengo un extraño problema y es que no funciona redirect, en ninguna parte de mi aplicación. ni siquiera al loguearse... al ejecutar la acción hace todos los procedimientos del método pero al redirigir se queda en la misma url y la pagina se pone en blanco.

```
'urlManager' => [ 
    'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager', 
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true, 
    'showScriptName' => false, 
    'rules'=>[ 
        ' ' => 'site/index', 
        'POST <controller:[\w-]+>s' => '<controller>/create', 
        '<controller:[\w-]+>s' => '<controller>/index', 
        'PUT <controller:[\w-]+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/update',
        'DELETE <controller:[\w-]+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/delete', 
        '<controller:[\w-]+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view', 
    ],
],
```

Comment: ¿podrías agregar tu código? así sería más fácil poder ayudarte

Comment: `'urlManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules'=>[
         ' ' => 'site/index',

    'POST <controller:[\w-]+>s' => '<controller>/create',
    '<controller:[\w-]+>s' => '<controller>/index',

    'PUT <controller:[\w-]+>/<id:\d+>'    => '<controller>/update',
    'DELETE <controller:[\w-]+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/delete',
    '<controller:[\w-]+>/<id:\d+>'        => '<controller>/view',
       ], 
    ],   `

Comment: Ese fue el ultimo codigo que modifique y luego surgio el error en to da la aplicacion... no redirige

Comment: Si el problema apareció de repente al modificar un archivo de configuración, puede ser debido a que ese archivo tenga un formato incorrecto. Revisa que no haya caracteres extra, y si usas UTF-8 asegúrate que esté codificado sin BOM (Byte Order Mark).

Comment: ¿Puedes agregar también el código de algún controlador que no redirija correctamente?

Comment: Asi estan todos los redirects y ninguno funciona. 

`public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('update', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }`
Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener acceso a los controladoees y acciones en base de métodos HTTP(PUT, POST, DELETE), las reglas debería definirse así:

```
[
    'PUT,POST <controller>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/create',
    'DELETE <controller>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/delete',
    '<controller>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
]
```

En este [enlace de documentanción](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-es/runtime-routing.md#m%C3%A9todos-http-) pueden encontrar más información detallada.